# Unstable solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to show that, for the function $f=f(x,y,z,t)$ satisfying the differential equation

$$-af+bf^{3}+\frac{d^{2}f}{dt^{2}}-\nabla^{2}f=0, \qquad a>0$$

$f=0$ is an unstable solution

How do I prove it?

---

My approach is to perturb the solution $f=0$ to $f=0+p$ and plug this into the differential equation.

We then have

$$-ap+bp^{3}+\frac{d^{2}p}{dt^{2}}-\nabla^{2}p=0.$$

Ignoring the cubic term (since $p$ is small), we have

$$-ap+\frac{d^{2}p}{dt^{2}}-\nabla^{2}p=0.$$

How do I then procees to show that $f=0$ is an unstable solution.

Comment: Take p constant then your linearized equation can be solved exactly very easily...

Comment: Why take $p$ to be constant in time?

Comment: Constant in space (so that the Laplacian vanishes).

Comment: Why is $p$ constant in space?

Comment: For convenience. To prove instability of an equilibrium it is essentially sufficient to find a particular initial condition near the equilibrium that is sent far from the equilibrium. Choosing that condition to be constant in space removes the spatial derivatives which simplifies the problem.

Comment: Okay, so then, we have $\ddot{p}=ap$, which has a complex exponential solution $p=A\exp(iat)+B\exp(-iat)$. How does this help?

Comment: No it doesn't, that would be the opposite sign on the coefficient. You have real exponentials instead.

Comment: Okay, so I have p=A\exp(at)+B\exp(-at). How does this help?

Comment: The first term blows up, if A is nonzero.

Comment: I considered a small perturbation $p$. How can $p$ then blow up?

Comment: I think you are really misunderstanding what you are doing. You are considering the problem with the initial condition $(u(0,x),u_t(0,x))=p(x)$, where $p(x)$ should be close to the zero function. (Here I'm writing $x$ for the vector $(x,y,z)$.) If $p$ is chosen to be, say, equal to $(\delta,0)$ for all $x$, where $\delta$ is any nonzero number, then the linearized equation for $u$ will diverge.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, my $\delta$ is not a small pertubation, then? It's just that, my initial condition is $\phi=0$?

Comment: Er, no, I'm saying that your initial condition is $p(x)=(u(0,x),u_t(0,x))=(\delta,0)$. If $\delta$ is small then this is a small perturbation of $q(x)=0$, which is what you wanted to perturb from.

Comment: Ok, if $p=\delta$ is my initial condition, then I can't really ignore the cubic term, can I?

Comment: You can for a short time, but yeah to make this rigorous you would need to prove that the cubic term doesn't break things.